# Department of education vs department for education

Tags: prepositions

Which one of below two sentence is correct?

> 1. The Department **for** Education said its decisions were based on new infections and the pressure on the NHS in local areas.
> 2. The Department **of** Education said its decisions were based on new infections and the pressure on the NHS in local areas.

Comment: Not long ago it was the Department for Children Schools and Families.  Governments change the names of the departments at whim.

Answer (score 10):

This isn't a question of grammar but of what the department is named, which varies from place to place and from era to era.

In the UK, it's called *the Department for Education* (but was known as *the Department of Education and Science* from 1964 to 1992, and *the Board of Education* pre-1964).

The quotation you give refers to the NHS (the UK National Health Service) so suggests a British context.

Comment: Yes, the UK Government for some reason decided to start using _for_ instead of _of_ in all its official names.

Comment: @KateBunting - not the Ministry of Justice (MoJ).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Interesting. _Ministry_ used to be the general term for government departments, but I thought they had all been changed to _Department_. (Speaking from memories of being a library cataloguer and having to cross-reference all the changes of name!)

Comment: @KateBunting You have (currently) Department of Health and Social Care (DHSC), Ministry of Defence, Ministry of Justice, plus a whole bunch of Departments _for_ something. The MOD seems to mainly use a capital 'O', and the MoJ a little 'o' in their abbreviations but these aren't official anyway. There are a number of _Ministerial Departments_ that have different name styles such as the Attorney General's Office, Cabinet Office, Foreign and Commonwealth Office, Home Office, HM Treasury, etc.

Comment: Just to add more confusion: there's also the [Home Office](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_Office), "which is considered to be one of the Great Offices of State, [and] continues to be known, especially in official papers and when referred to in Parliament, as the Home Department."

Comment: More generally, my impression is that when a department's name is changed, 'of' may become 'for' - or vice versa - _in addition to_ any other changes, to make a clear distinction between the old and new names. As this answer shows, words may also be added to or removed from the name; and sometimes the word order may be changed, e.g. London Transport became Transport for London.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff when there is a court case against the Home Office the case will be named 'Joe Bloggs v Secretary of State for the Home Department (or SSHD for short)

Answer (score 2):

Both should be proper grammar, but we usually say "The Department of Education" as in the second sentence.

Actually there is both:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Department_for_Education

The above is "Department for Education".

And:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Department_of_Education

Is "Department of Education".

I think in the UK they maybe use "for" too, but in the US it's "of".

Answer (score 2):

Both are used.

If it’s a proper name, then it uses whatever the proper name uses. In the US this is usually ‘of’ for governmental departments, while in the UK it’s usually ‘for’ for governmental departments.

If it’s not a proper name (which is rare), it’s entirely up to the person speaking, but will usually follow whichever form they are more used to.

In either case, you may also instead see ‘Education Department’ or similar constructs where the purpose of the department is listed first, though that seems to be more commonly used in businesses or universities than in governments.

---

Of possible note, both forms can be argued to be shortened forms of ‘Department for the management/handling/oversight/purpose of X’. English likes to keep titles short whenever possible. See for example how ‘Doctor’ is often used in preference to referencing the area of study of the individual’s doctoral degree (and the confusion this sometimes causes when people who are not medical doctors insist on usage of the title ‘Doctor’ in general contexts).

Answer (score -3):

While both are used, it doesn't make both right. A department does work on behalf of its constituents, so the correct grammar is 'for'. By saying that a department is 'of', then it implies that it IS the constituents, which isn't the case.